# SharePoint 2010: Possible to restrict PeoplePicker from displaying AD users in a claims-based web site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a claims based site in 2010, using FBA (SQL), and AD.  I would like when the forms users login to not see AD results in the peoplepicker.  This was possible in 2007 using:

```
stsadm -o setproperty

   -propertyname peoplepicker-nowindowsaccountsfornonwindowsauthenticationmode
```

How can I do this in 2010?  If I try to disable AD for the site, I get a warning saying Search will not be able to crawl this site.

Any thoughts?

donal

Answer (score 0):

To get search to work when you are using FBA, you need to extend the SharePoint Application, creating a new site that uses windows authentication, and shares the same content database.

See: http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2010/01/sharepoint-2010-forms-based.html